# Makefile Error "file requires compiler and library support"

Tags: c++, makefile

My makefile is showing me this error [image] telling me that i should use -std=c++11 so i did but it keeps showing me this error .

here is the includes needed to compile the file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <limits>
```

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall
EXEC_NAME = MyLzw
INCLUDES =
LIBS =
OBJ_FILES = lzw.cpp
INSTALL_DIR = /usr/bin

all : $(EXEC_NAME)

clean :
    rm $(EXEC_NAME) $(OBJ_FILES)

$(EXEC_NAME) : $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) -o $(EXEC_NAME) $(OBJ_FILES) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

install :
    cp $(EXEC_NAME) $(INSTALL_DIR)
```

EDIT : When i compile manually everything works fine :
[image]

Comment: Can you try isolating the error by invoking the exact command that leads to the error? The issue doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the makefile.

Comment: Does a run of `make` output g++ commands that look correct? Do you get the same error if you just copy and paste one of those g++ commands?

Comment: (Traditionally, `$(CC)` and `$(CFLAGS)` are for C, and `$(CXX)` and `$(CXXFLAGS)` are for C++. But since you have manually defined and used the variables here, I wouldn't expect that to cause a problem.)

Comment: @lubgr the exact command shows no error

Comment: ... and if you add `-I/usr/include/' and ` -c -o lzw.o ` ? This is the exact command that the makefile invokes.

Comment: @lubgr Sorry .. i edited my post is it fine ?

Comment: @lubgr I'm really sorry i usually use IDE so i'm kinda lost what should i write exactly so i compile it correctly?

Comment: How do you expect `/usr/bin` and `/usr/include` to work on Windows?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The makefiles works just fine now and the includes was because i needed to share my makefile to someone using Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in your makefile.

Your "object files" (`$(OBJ_FILES)`) are specified to be the source files (i.e. `lzw.cpp`). This is sort of fine, because `g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp -o exec` is valid.

But that "final" recipe (the one that builds `$(EXEC_NAME)`) doesn't mention `$(CFLAGS)`; you've left that for the building of `.o` files, which makes sense, or would if you were building any `.o` files.

I think you meant:

```
OBJ_FILES = lzw.o
```